# Do extra commands in Texstudio

Tags: texstudio

In texstudio, is it possible to add a customize commands that will be executed when building the pdf?

For example, I want to execute `mycommand (%filne_name).pdf` right after I press `F5` and the pdf is built.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Options->Configure TeXstudio, then go to the Build tab and add your command at the end of the Build & View[image]

Comment: Will those commands be executed after the meta commands or before? WHat is the parameter for the file name of the generated pdf?

Comment: Should be after, just as it first compiles then views